# Shapeless error while trying trying to use PureConfig and Circe for scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, circe, pureconfig

```
shapeless.DefaultSymbolicLabelling  
shapeless.DefaultSymbolicLabelling$.instance(shapeless.HList)
```

getting this error while using both `pureconfig` and `circe`.
I'm using spark 3.1.2 with spark k8s operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because of conflicting shapeless library versions. Spark 3.1.2 ships with shapeless 2.3.3 whereas both these packages need shapeless 2.3.7. To solve this I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-use-pureconfig-with-spark-210-problematic-shapeless-dependency) which involve shading ie renaming the dependency.

**For SBT**

If you are using the sbt-assembly plugin to create your JARs you can [shade](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) shapeless by adding to your assembly.sbt file the following setting:

```
assembly / assemblyShadeRules := Seq(ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "new_shapeless.@1").inAll)
```

**Maven**

The [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) can shade shapeless by adding to your pom.xml file the following block:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <relocations>
            <relocation>
                <pattern>shapeless</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>shapelesspureconfig</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
        </relocations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have the same issue but I couldnt find my assembly.sbt file. I am using Intellij IDEA

Comment: Do you happen to know where should I add the shade rules? I am using sbt but I only got plugin and build sbt files.

Comment: @CodingStark Just add them to build.sbt

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work

Comment: I use assembly.sbt is used to make fat jars. Follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-fat-jar) to set it up. I have named it assembly.sbt under the project folder, whereas the tutorial has named it plugins.sbt. If you are using Injellij, you can go to the sbt shell and type assembly (ctrl + shift + s) to make the fat jar